Composition of locally bounded predictable processes
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0},P)$ be a filtered probability space, $X_t$ be a locally bounded predictable $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued process and $F:[0,\infty)\times \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} $ be a $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\backslash \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function such that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $F(\cdot,\cdot,x)$ is a locally bounded predictable process. Can we conclude that $G(t,\omega)\colon=F(t,\omega,X_t(\omega))$ is a locally bounded predictable process?
By locally bounded, I mean stochastic localization, i.e. $X$ is locally bounded if there exists a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n \uparrow\infty$ such that the stopped process $1_{\{\tau_n>0\}}X^{\tau_n}$ is uniformly bounded.
I think for the predictability the answer is yes and proof should be something similar to item (c) of this answer (using $\pi-\lambda$ sets). But I am having a hard time figuring out what the starting $\Sigma$ set should be. For the local boundedness part the difficulty is that $X$ and $F$ could have different localizing sequences and I am not sure if taking the maximum would be enough.

I think the item a) in @saz's answer is wrong, so I posted another question related to this, just give you a warning that not every answer is correct thou.

There are a few things not clear in your question such as: what kind of measurability of $F$ are you referring to? And what do you mean by local boundedness?
Nevertheless, here is an answer that could help you. We begin with some notations. Set $W := [0,\infty) \times \Omega$ and regard a $w \in W$ as a pair $(t,\omega)$. With this , the map $X:W\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $w \mapsto X(w)$ is a $\mathcal P$-measurable map, where $\mathcal P$ is the predictable $\sigma$-algebra of $W$. Also, $F$ is now regarded as a map from the product space $W \times \mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, which maps $(w,x) \mapsto F(w,x)$.
Assumption 1: The map $(w,x) \mapsto F(w,x)$ is $\mathcal P \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$-measurable.
Now we need to prove $w \mapsto F(w,X(w))$ is $\mathcal P$-measurable. Notice that the map
$$ i: W \rightarrow W\times \mathbb R^n, \quad w \mapsto i(w) =(w,X(w)) $$
is $\mathcal P\setminus \mathcal P \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$ measurable because
$$ \forall A \in \mathcal P, \ \forall B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n), \qquad i^{-1} (A\times B)= \{w \in W: (w,X(w))\in A\times B \} = A \cap X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal P.  $$
Therefore, write $w \mapsto F(w,X(w))$ as the composition $w \mapsto F\circ i(w)$, we see it is $\mathcal P$-measurable. In other words, $(t,\omega) \mapsto F(t,\omega, X_t(\omega))$ is a predictable process.
Without Assumption 1, the map $w \mapsto F(w,X(w))$ may not be predictable. In the assumption in your question, only the map $w \mapsto F(w,x)$ is measurable for each $x$ and this looks like a stochastic process indexed by $x \in \mathbb R^n$ but without the joint-measurability condition with respect to the product algebra $\mathcal P \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$. And you may have known that a stochastic process may not be jointly measurable! Also the map $i$ is not $ \mathcal P\setminus \mathcal C \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$ measurable, where $\mathcal C$ is another bigger $\sigma$-algebra!
To get rid of this problem you may need to specify what kind of measurability $F$ has or impose a bit more regularity assumptions on $F$ such as $x \mapsto F(w,x)$ is right (or left) continuous to have $F$ satisfy Assumption 1.
Why is it different from the proof using $\pi-\lambda$ system in the link you give? This is because the function $g: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ there does not have $\omega$ in its arguments, which is easier. A straight forward example for why it is more complicated is the theory of stochastic processes, where there are a lot of measurability issues and probabilists have to give a lot of notions of measurability like jointly, progressive, predictable  etc...

Thanks, very helpful. I added more details as to what I mean by measurability and local boundedness. I guess  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\backslash \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurability and $F(\cdot,\cdot,x)$ being $\mathcal{P}\backslash \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ does not imply $\mathcal{P}\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \backslash \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurability for $F$ because of the joint measurability issue. Is that right? Also, do you have any insight for the locally bounded property? Thanks!

For the first question, yes, think about classical examples of stochastic processes, without jointly measurability there are a lot of issues. For the second question, from your definition of local boundedness, the function $F(\omega, t, X_t(\omega)$ may not behave well, so a condition such as $x \mapsto F(\cdot,\cdot,x)$ to be bounded, uniformly in the first 2 arguments may be necessary. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that $(t,\omega) \mapsto F(...)$ is locally bounded at all.

First question: yes (agree with @Jao). Local boundedness of the process $G(t,\omega)$ should depend on the regularity and properties of $F$ not solely on the process $X$. Therefore, as pointed out by @Jao, you must put more assumptions on $F$

@LNT Thanks. In the question, there is also the assumption that $F(\cdot,\cdot,x)$ for each $x$ is locally bounded (assume the localization sequence is the same for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$). So both $X$ and $F(\cdot,\cdot,x)$ (for each $x$) are locally bounded. Wouldn't that be enough?

Yeah, I saw that, but I'm sure in general $G$ would not be locally bounded. For example let $F(\cdot,\cdot, x) = 1/|x| $ then clearly it's a uniformly bounded process for each $x$ since it's constant. But if the process $X(t,\omega)$ can go to $0$ (this is irrelevant of its local boundedness), then $w \mapsto F(w,X(w)) = 1/|X(w)|$ can exploded!
